# Is it possible to get a shiny Tapu Fini, or is it shinylocked?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

I really want a shiny Tapu Fini, but I’m pretty sure they’re shinylocked. Is there any way to get one?

Answer (score 3):

Yes [Tapu Fini is shiny locked](https://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml). There were [events last year](https://www.serebii.net/events/dex/788.shtml) that distributed shiny Tapu Fini. You will need to find someone with one who is willing to trade their shiny Tapu Fini to you.